# How to get count of matching strings in a large table

Tags: mysql, sql, string, count

I have a table with following structure:

```
+-----+-------------------+
| ID  | Name              |
+-----+-------------------+
|   1 | abc               |
+-----+-------------------+
|   2 | abc (duplicate)   |
+-----+-------------------+
|   3 | bcd               |
+-----+-------------------+
|   4 | bcd (duplicate)   |
+-----+-------------------+
|   5 | bcd (duplicate)   |
+-----+-------------------+
|   6 | efg               |
+-----+-------------------+
|   7 | hij               |
+-----+-------------------+
```

I need to count each `Name` occurance (with `(duplicate)` included), i.e.:

```
+-------------------+--------+
| Name              | Count  |
+-------------------+--------+
| abc               |      2 |
+-------------------+--------+
| bcd               |      3 |
+-------------------+--------+
| efg               |      1 |
+-------------------+--------+
| hij               |      1 |
+-------------------+--------+
```

I want to mention, that `Name` column is actually have type `TINYTEXT`. And there will be very lot of rows in it: **5396** in *test mode* already. I tried to make self join of table by `TRIM(REPLACE(Name, '(duplicate)', ''))` with grouping:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT TRIM(REPLACE(`t`.`Name`, '(duplicate)', '')) as `name`,
    COUNT(`s`.`ID`) as `count`
FROM
    `Table` as `t` INNER JOIN `Table` as `s` ON
        TRIM(REPLACE(`t`.`Name`, '(duplicate)', '')) LIKE TRIM(REPLACE(`s`.`Name`, '(duplicate)', ''))
GROUP BY 1;
```

And... Well, it took **122.62** sec (?!) with result of 4846 rows on my development machine.

---

***Q1:*** Was it a correct approach?

***Q2:*** Is there any way to make it faster?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, you actually add **(dublicate)** in the *dublicate* columns?

Comment: There are no such marker. Should be?

Comment: Are all names 3 characters in length?

Comment: @Mr47 No, 3-255 characters. Table collation is `utf-8`.

Comment: Could you count the number of times `name(duplicate)` occurs and just add 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "duplicate" text:

```
select replace(name, ' (duplicate)', ''), count(*)
from mytable
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Looks like I need a clear head right now... I was thinking wrong way after a writing of a lot complex queries.

Comment: No worries. Out of interest, does the accepted answer give the sand results as mins? I'm sure my query is correct. I'm not sure what effect the "distinct" keyword will have though. Let be know

Comment: I have no `DISTINCT` in my query now. `GROUP BY 1` doing the same. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

This should be quicker, although with that many rows you're basically storing a growing array of objects that you're counting and since it's a `TINYTEXT` field it can be immense.

```
select Name,count(ID) from Table group by Name
```

I see what you're saying now. Here's an updated SQL:

```
select DISTINCT TRIM(REPLACE(Name, ' (duplicate)', ''))
as name, count(ID) from Table group by name
```

Comment: It doesn't help. `(duplicate)`s should be counted inclusive. `:(`

Comment: So you have fields with the word "duplicate" in them?

Comment: Yes, I am. I need them to be counted. Though, looks like I found where was my mistake.

Comment: Thanks. Sich a noobish mistake... Your update is looks like my query.